# Animate painter2D in Vector API Uitoolkit Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, unity3d-gui

Is it possible to animate the LineTo method of a MeshGenerationContext to have a smooth movement from the current position to the final one?

```
void Draw(MeshGenerationContext mgc)
{
        var painter2D = mgc.painter2D;

        painter2D.fillColor = wireColor;

        painter2D.BeginPath();
        painter2D.MoveTo(p0);
        painter2D.LineTo(p1);
        painter2D.ClosePath();
        painter2D.Fill();
}
```